# Is this code JavaScript vulnerable to DOM based XSS?

Tags: xss, javascript, dom

I have some JS code below that is redirecting to a location taken from a HTML form. Is this vulnerable to an attack like DOM based XSS?

```
document.theform.reference.onchange = function(){
    var id = document.theform.reference.selectedIndex;
    var url = document.theform.reference[id].value;
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is: it depends. Depends on a lot of information not present in the question, and is not possible to include in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is vulnerable if `document.theform.reference[id].value` can be a value controlled by another user.

If this value was set to `javascript:alert('xss')` by an attacker then the line

```
window.location.href = url;
```

would cause the script to be executed in the context of the current domain for whichever user is currently using the site.

Comment: But I assume it also depends on the way it is user controllable. If the user just enters a value in a form from which JS takes it, than I do not see any way an attacker could use that. The user could of course execute JS in his browser by entering javascript:alert() in the form field, but that would mean he is attacking himself. In order for a real XSS vulnerability to exist, I assume an attacker must also be able to somehow send the page to the victim with the url or the form value already populated with the malicious JS.

Comment: Thanks Silverlight & pineappleman - Since it seems vulnerable to dom xss, if possible pls post how to execute? I need to put payload in form field?!
If its self-xss, i tink attacer can exploit via CSRF or Clickjacking, if the page is vulnerable...right?

Comment: @DaveMn: There's not enough information in your question to see how your form operates and where the form is populated from.

Comment: This can also work through url parameter eg like http://foo.com?parameter_tobe_added_in_document_href=javascript:alert("xss"). @SilverlightFox thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code, I assume that the user is entering the URL parameter into a form.

As @SilverlightFox said, an attacker could enter `javascript:alert('xss')` in the form, and that would execute the JS, but only in his browser. Since the URL parameter is not part of the URL of the website (either as a GET parameter or somehow else) and is not stored anywhere, I do not see a way an attacker could make another user execute JS code, except convincing him to manually enter the malicious code into the form.

But since XSS is a complicated topic, and I do not have insight in the whole application code, I would still make some precautions.

First, it is important to limit the URLs a user can enter. Hardcode the beginning of the URL, at least the http:// part. That would make sure that nobody can enter a URL with a different protocol like javascript:.

Also, if possible, limit the URLs that can be entered to your domain only. If a user can enter other domains, issue a warning that they are leaving your site.

If you are inserting the url parameter anywhere else in the code, make sure to use the proper output encoding.